# Referential integrity constraint violation on delete in a onttomany relationship

Tags: spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I am getting the below error when trying to delete a entity with `one-to-many` relationship. i.e `Order` to `LineItems`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
public class Order {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order",
               cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
               fetch = FetchType.EAGER
            )
    private Set<LineItem> lineItems;
    ...
```

LineItem

```
@Entity
@Table(name="line_items")
public class LineItem {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="order_id", nullable = false)
    private Order order;
```

JPA:

```
 @Modifying
    @Query("delete  from Order o where o.id=?1")
    void  deleteById(Long id);
```

Error

```
Referential integrity constraint violation: "FKCFMX8JQMQU18HHASFDF3W1M9U: PUBLIC.LINE_ITEMS FOREIGN KEY(ORDER_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.ORDERS(ID) (29)"; SQL statement:
delete from orders where id=?
```

Answer (score 0):

If you delete an entity using an HQL query, Spring Data is only going to run the HQL query you have specified. This mean that it will try to delete the row in the table `orders` without checking if there is a reference to the row in the table `line_items`. This is what causing the exception.

You don't need a custom query for this:

```
@Repository
public interface OrderRepository extends CrudRepository<Order, Long> {
    long deleteById(Long id);
}
```